# Vb.net button still allows click while disabled

Tags: vb.net, button

My button is responding to clicks while disabled.

```
Private Sub btnGenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click
        btnGenerate.Enabled = False
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

        'Do a bunch of operations

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        btnGenerate.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```

It takes about 5-10 seconds to process the stuff I'm doing in the background.  During that 5-10 seconds the button is greyed out, but if I click it a second time, then it performs the operational stuff a second time after finishing the first.

I'm missing something here.  How can I prevent button from allowing interaction until operations are finished?

Comment: I suggest to use a BackgroundWorker to move your intensive task out of the way and reenable the button when the worker has completed its task

Comment: @Steve - I can understand suggesting a background worker, but disabling/reenabling the button still doesn't work.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @user432209 I am curious how this turned out for you... do you have an update?

Comment: @JStevens - I got sidetracked....still have to come back to this later.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Working as boolean=false

Private Sub btnGenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click
    if Working=true then exit sub

    ' Your Work Process
    Work()
End Sub

sub Work()
   Working=True

   ' Work code

   Working=False
end sub
```

this should prevent the double click

Answer (score 0):

With VS2012, Async Work is very easy to use (compared to previous versions...).

The problem is the UI thread is not letting go.  Without seeing what 'work' is actually going on, I can not explain why.  I am hoping nothing that re enables the button...

However, Async will allow release of the UI thread and the enabled = false should take effect.  Try something like this:

```
Private Async Sub btnGenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click
    btnGenerate.Enabled = False
    Dim t As New Task(Sub() MyWorkLoad())
    t.Start()
    Await t
    btnGenerate.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub MyWorkLoad()
   'do your work here

   'for testing
    Dim time As Date = Now
    Do While True
        If DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, -5, Now) > time Then Exit Do
    Loop

End Sub
```

This did work for me...
[image: This did work for me]

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to give this a try.  To answer your question the work is basically reading and writing out text files (hence why it takes 5-10 sec).  I am curious as to why it makes a difference?

Comment: I will also add, that if you replace my work with `Thread.Sleep(5000)` the problem still occurs, so what I'm doing shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: To answer why I wanted to know what is was that you are doing for "work",  events are tricky.  If you work was firing other events, things would get complicated.  A whole slew of things was racing through my brain at the time... more details is always better than fewer...

Comment: @user432209 I am sorry, I was wrong.  `Thread.Sleep` inside the MyWorkLoad sub would not be on the UI thread.  So if your Sub only had `Thread.Sleep(5000)` in it, it should work.  It did test with no issue.

Comment: But I will still say, using `Thread.Sleep` when testing for thread blocking is not always a good thing... a controlled loop will not block any threads.